# Map Virtual path to physical path

Tags: vb.net, server.mappath

I have an issue with the method Server.MapPath.

I am currently using the method `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("MyPath")` to obtain the physical path of "MyPath" in an ApiController, get method.

If I try to use the same method in an ApiController which returns an HttpResponse, it gives the error:

> `Current` is not a member of `System.Net.Http.HttpContent`

How can I use the method `Server.MapPath` in the context of an `HttpResponseMessage`?

(I am working in Visual Basic)

Edit: I am using it like this:

```
<HttpGet>
Public Function MyFunc() As HttpResponseMessage
    Try
        Dim streamContent = New PushStreamContent(_
                       Function(outputStream, httpContext, transportContent)
         Try
Dim lPath = httpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(MyPath)

        .... some code

                End Try
    End Function)
 Dim lResult = New HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
 lResult.Content = streamContent

 Return lResult
    End Try
   End Function
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've just mistyped/intellisense has helped you to type `HttpContent` when you wanted to type `HttpContext`?

Comment: I attached the exact code I used. I am using HttpContext. However, I am also using HttpContext in the function there, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: I've rolled your edit back. It's useful for people to see the actual code. Also, without the code in the question, it makes me appear psychic, which is unwarranted (in this case) to know exactly where the fault lay in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument passed to your callback function is of type `HttpContent`. You're effectively hiding `HttpContext` inside your lambda because you're named that parameter `HttpContext`. Try:

```
Dim streamContent = New PushStreamContent(_
    Function(outputStream, content, transportContent) 'Renamed parameter here
         Try
             Dim lPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(MyPath)

         '.... some code
         Catch ex As Exception
         Finally
             outputStream.Close()
         End Try
    End Function)
```

The [`PushStreamContent` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127067%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) definition is:

```
Public Sub New ( _
    onStreamAvailable As Action(Of Stream, HttpContent, TransportContext) _
)
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem, I just noticed it, I solved it by using System.Web.HttpContext, but your solution is a better one. thank you